# Expand distance between values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to expand distance between values in pandas dataframe?

```
  A
1 3
2 5
3 6
5 5
6 9
```

I want to increase the distance between adjacent elements by x times, for example by two times.

Expected output:

```
  A B
1 3 3
2 5 7  # (3 + 2 * 2)
3 6 9  # (7 + 1 * 2)
5 5 7  # (9 - 1 * 2)
6 9 15 # (7 + 4 * 2)
```

Comment: That's just `B = A*2 - A[0]`. For example, on row 1 `B = 3*2 - 3 = 3` and for row 6 `B = 9*2 - 3 = 15`

Comment: @MatBailie that's true, well done, but I believe It's important to explain why. I added some explanation in my answer, let me know if you prefer to add your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use a vectorial code as suggested by @MatBailie:

```
df['B'] = df['A']*2 - df['A'].iloc[0]
```

For generic code with any `N`:

```
N = 2
df['B'] = df['A']*N - df['A'].iloc[0]*(N-1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B(N=1)  B(N=2)  B(N=3)
1  3       3       3       3
2  5       5       7       9
3  6       6       9      12
5  5       5       7       9
6  9       9      15      21
```

Some explanation is however needed to understand why:

For each step, assuming `a(n)` the current value and `b(n)` the output. The output `b(n)` is equal to `b(n-1) + (a(n) - a(n-1)) * 2`, which is equal to `b(n-2) + (a(n-1) - a(n-2)) * 2 + (a(n) - a(n-1)) * 2` which simplifies to `b(n-2) + (a(n) - a(n-1)) * 2)`. By recursion, this becomes `b(n) = b(0) + (a(n) - a(0))*2` which is `b(n) = 2*a(n) - a(0)` if `n=2` since `b(0)` = `a(0)`, in the generic case this is `b(n) = a(n)*N - a(0)*(N-1)`.

Output:

```
   A   B
1  3   3
2  5   7
3  6   9
5  5   7
6  9  15
```

---

Original answer:

<s>You probably can't solve it in a vectorial way since your nth value depends on the output of the step n-1</s>, I believe you must iterate:

```
def expand_dist(s):
    s = list(s)
    prev = s[0]
    out = []
    for v in s:
        out.append(prev+(v-prev)*2)
    return out

df['B'] = expand_dist(df['A'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77778336/expand-distance-between-values-in-pandas-dataframe/77778460#comment137117900_77778336) - multiple `A` by `2` and subtract first value:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].mul(2) - df['A'].iat[0]
print (df)
   A   B
1  3   3
2  5   7
3  6   9
5  5   7
6  9  15
```

Comment: Thank You, my friend, it works as expected. But there is 1 thing. It is not important at all, but I expect that with mul(1) my B column will be the same as A column (unchanged, no expansion). With Your desicion they are different.

Comment: @IgorK. it's because you have to add a factor to the second term (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77778427))

Comment: @IgorK. - Sorry, I was away, I see mozway create general solution.